# Using If-Else statement to check for output on Bash scripting

Tags: bash

I would want the bash scripting to run the following command

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000
```

if there is no output of it found using

```
iptables -t nat --list
```

How can I use the If-Else to look for the output. Can i use 'cat' ?

Answer (score 2):

Use **`$()`** to capture the output of a command and **`-z`** to determine if it is empty:

```
output=$(iptables -t nat --list)
if [ -z $output ] # returns true if the length of $output is 0
then
    output=$(iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000)
fi
```

Comment: I don't think they just want `iptables -t nat --list` to be empty, it pretty much never will be since it prints headers if nothing else.  I think they want to check if that routing rule is already there, which would be the "of it" in their expression--though of course I can't be sure that's what they mean

Comment: @EricRenouf I didn't know that, thanks for the heads-up. In that case I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep with the iptables list, depending on how you're trying to match it.

```
if iptables -t nat --list PREROUTING | grep -- '--destintation-port 80' | grep -q -- '--to-port 10000'
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000
fi
```

This will look if there is a PREROUTING entry that concerns both --destination-port 80 and --to-port 10000.  If the output string is more predictable you could use a single grep for it, but I don't know iptables well enough to offer that as part of the solution