# line 7: [: too many arguments in Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

So I was trying to do a if-else to check if there's anything listed using iptables -t nat --list but I encountered an error saying too many arguments in line 7.

```
output=$(iptables -t nat --list)
if [ -z $output ] 
then 
 output=$(iptables -t nat - A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j...)
fi
```

Comment: You may find [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful.

Answer (score 4):

Either quote `$output` or use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]`

```
if [ -z "$output" ]; then
```

or

```
if [[ -z $output ]]; then
```

should work

The problem was that your `output` variable has spaces in it, so they get expanded and treated as separate arguments within `[ ]`, but the `-z` test only expects a single value, so it complains that it has the wrong number of arguments

Note, as per [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157440/using-if-else-statement-to-check-for-output-on-bash-scripting) the other day, the output of `iptables -t nat --list` will probably never be empty since it always prints at least the headers so you will probably never reach the body of this `if`